# Standard conventions for indicating a function argument is unused in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, unused-variables

Are there any standard ways of marking a function argument as unused in JavaScript, analogous to starting a method argument with an underscore in Ruby?

Comment: From what i have seen so far, its still `_` that's being used.

Comment: If you're looking to remove unused variables use [jslint](http://jslint.com)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Just so we have an example to work from, this is fairly common with jQuery's `$.each` where you're writing code that doesn't need the index, just the value, in the iteration callback and you're using `this` (which jQuery also sets to the value) for something else:

```
$.each(objectOrArrayLikeThing, (_, value) => {
    // Use `value` here
});
```

*(Yes, `$.each` passes arguments to the callback backward compared to the JavaScript standard `forEach`.)*

Using `_` is the closest I've seen to a standard way to do that, yes, but I've also seen lots of others — giving it a name reflective of its purpose anyway (`index`), combining those (`_index`), calling it `unused`, etc.

If you need to ignore more than one parameter, you can't repeat the same identifier (it's [disallowed in strict mode](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors), which should be everyone's default and is the default in modules and `class` constructs), so you have do things like `_0` and `_1` or `_` and `__`, etc. I've almost never had to do that, but when I have, I've used a name indicating what the parameter's value would be (`_index` for the `$.each` example, for instance).

Comment: you can't do function (_, _, value) though

Comment: @HanmingZeng - Indeed not. :-( You have to do things like `(_0, _1, value)` or (in my case) `(unused0, unused1, value)`. I've also seen `(_, __, value)` but...yikes. :-) There was a strawman proposal to allow blank parameter names once upon a time but it never went anywhere.

Comment: In Chromium it seems to work just fine to write a function declaration like `function (_, _, a) { … }` (of course inside the function the variable `_` only contains the second passed argument) but there's no error and the function is created (and works) just fine.

Comment: @zrajm - Only in loose mode. In strict mode, duplicate parameter names are disallowed. (It's best to always use strict mode except in rare situations where you can't. It's also the default for modules and the content of `class` constructs.)

Answer (score 64):

Using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), one can do:

```js
function f(...[, , third]) {
  console.log(third);
}

f(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: This seem more simpler to me.

Comment: I went with this solution since eslint would raise an error when I use `_`:
Variable name `_` must match one of the following formats: camelCase, PascalCase, UPPER_CASE

Answer (score 29):

With browsers supporting destructuring one can do:

```
function ({}, {}, value) {
  // console.log(value)
}
```

Which is kind of neat in that it avoids the problem of multiple arguments  having the same name and also won't create problems with libraries that assign methods to `_` (lodash, underscore, etc.).

One problem with this approach is that unused arguments of type `undefined` or `null` will throw.

For `undefined` one solution is to use default parameters:

```
function ({}={}, {}={}, value) {
  // console.log(value)
}
```

Sadly no such easily applied solution for `null`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this throws if an unused argument is `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: @OlegsJeremejevs
`function ({}={}, {}={}, value) { ... }` helps here, but it becomes messy...

Comment: @oluckyman Nice workaround! "Don't want to name an unused arg? Just dumbbell it!"

Comment: Wow, I always thought that destructuring a primitive value, i.e. `(function({}={}){})(0)` or `var {a}=0` will throw.

Answer (score 18):

I would recommend this syntax:

```
function(_index, value) {...}
```

to not to shadow lodash variable and still have description of argument in case if it will be used.

VS Code is also highlight these names properly and these unused args won't be deleted after autofix code smells

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `function` `arguments` object?

```js
function third() { const [,,thirdArg] = arguments;
  return thirdArg;
}
console.log(third(1,2,3));
```

Comment: I like the answer by @Joseph Marinier even better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197927/standard-conventions-for-indicating-a-function-argument-is-unused-in-javascript/58738236#58738236

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: For unused parameters to be ignore from unused errors using:

```
function(_1, _2, toBeUseParam) { ... }
```