# Omit property variable when using object destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, object-destructuring

Here is an example:

```
const initObject = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
}

const { a, ...rest } = initObject
```

We're omitting property `a` from the object, but then `const a` is assigned a value, but never used - error from eslint (no-unused-vars). Is it possible to completely omit `const a`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A possible way is to use `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars`

e.g.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const { a, ...rest } = initObject
```

Or by using [`ignoreRestSiblings`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#ignorerestsiblings)

> The ignoreRestSiblings option is a boolean (default: false). Using a Rest Property it is possible to “omit” properties from an object, but by default the sibling properties are marked as “unused”. With this option enabled the rest property’s siblings are ignored.

e.g.

```
/*eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "ignoreRestSiblings": true }]*/
// 'a' is ignored because it has a rest property sibling.
const { a, ...rest } = initObject;
```

More info about [`no-unused-vars`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars)

---

But if your goal is to remove the property `a`, there is another way.
You can use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator.

From [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#wiki-content)

> The JavaScript **`delete`** **operator** removes a property from an object

e.g.

```js
const initObject = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
}

const rest = { ...initObject }; // create a shallow copy
delete rest.a;

console.log(rest);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to disable the warning, i want to do it "the right way" :)

Comment: Well, guess i'll just ignore it. But i wonder, how unused vars are affecting an app performance?

Comment: @AlexanderKim Interesting question. But unfortunately I haven't answers about performance of unused variable.

Comment: Seems like `delete` is a better option, indeed.

Comment: Why you have changed `const rest = initObject` to `const rest = { ...initObject }` ?

Comment: @AlexanderKim because they're different. If you reference `initObject` instead of creating a shallow copy, `delete rest.a` will also modify `initObject`.

Answer (score 26):

> error from eslint (no-unused-vars).

The [no-unused-vars rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) has two configuration options that will help with your use case:

- The [`ignoreRestSiblings` option](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#ignorerestsiblings) is a boolean that defaults to `false`. When enabled, the rest property’s siblings are ignored. This is **exactly** what you need!
- The [`varsIgnorePattern` option](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#varsignorepattern) specifies a regexp pattern for variable names not to be checked for usage. This allows us to make an exception for the [common](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41085189/1048572) [underscore identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32197927/1048572) to explicitly mark unused variables with `{ "varsIgnorePattern": "^_" }`.

  ```
  const { a:_, ...rest } = initObject;
  //       ^^
  ```

  Unfortunately you still need to avoid multiple declarations of the `_` variable, so to omit multiple properties you'd need to do something like `{ a:_a, b:_b, ...rest } = …`.

> Is it possible to completely omit `const a`?

A bad hack that completely avoids introducing any identifier would be to use

```
const { a:{}, ...rest } = initObject;
//       ^^^
```

that further destructures the `.a` property value into an object, but for this you need to ensure that the property exists and doesn't hold a `null` or `undefined` value.

Comment: I didn't know about these two rules but this was literally the first thing I suggested in comments (it's deleted now). Have my upvote

Comment: By the way, for your last block, `const { a: {} = {}, ...rest } = initObject` would allow `a` to be `undefined` but looks even worse.

Answer (score 10):

This may seem a trivial deviation from [@R3tep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56151883/1541563), but it avoids the pitfall of marking all the variables in the declaration as used:

```
const initObject = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
}

const {
  a, // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  ...rest
} = initObject
```

Now if `rest` is unused, it will still cause an eslint error.

---

In regards to the question

> what's the correct way to remove a property then?

I'm going to answer the question you should have asked instead. The correct way to *handle an object with properties you don't need* is to rewrite your logic in a way that *implicitly* ignores them.

1. If you just need the properties `b` and `c`, destructure only those properties:

   ```
   const { b, c } = initObject
   ```

   Don't even acknowledge that `a` exists if you don't need it.
2. If your input has a lot of **specific** properties you need to deal with, and you can't assume that `initObject` already has the *exact* layout it needs, then *avoid* the temptation to use reflection methods or syntax like [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [object spread and rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals), etc.

   Continue to handle the specific properties you need on an individual basis, and break up your logic into separable functions that each deal with a manageable subset of the properties, if necessary.

   On the other hand, if you *can* precondition your input to have the exact layout you already need (e.g. you are able to assume that `initObject` only has `b` and `c`), then feel free to use reflection -- that's exactly what it's for.
3. If neither of the above two points applies to you and you still find that you really want `initObject` to have a lot of **arbitrary** properties, and a few that you want to ignore, *then* you should use the suggestion at the beginning of this answer (or one of the other answers that works for you).

   However, as noted, this is code-smell and an indicator that your logic needs to be more lenient with the layout of the object<sup>1</sup>, or your preconditions for the input need to change<sup>2</sup>.

Comment: Thanks, what about performance, if i'm gonna have loads of places with unused vars?

Comment: But, if after evaluating what I just pointed out, this is still deemed necessary, then performance-wise it's about the equivalent of declaring an unused pointer, which is to say that it's negligible. Anyway it's possible the optimizer will notice it's unused and remove the declaration entirely.

Comment: @AlexanderKim the performance cost is actually in the `...rest` part, which iterates over the remaining properties of `initObject` and copies them to `rest`, and is part of the reason it's considered code-smell.

Comment: @AlexanderKim You can use the operator [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: @AlexanderKim Performance costs are worthless to think about until they've 1) become an issue, and 2) you've profiled to be sure of exactly where your performance bottleneck is. Optimizing out 1 millisecond and 4 bytes isn't going to help you in 100% of usecases that you're using JavaScript with.

Comment: @Delioth 1ms is a lot. Here we are rather talking about 1/100μs or less. And your point stands better.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a IIFE and pass object to it.

```js
const initObject = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
}
const res = (({a,...rest}) => (a,rest))(initObject);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: It's possible that eslint would still complain about this. (My solution would be to ignore eslint, but that's just me.)

Comment: @Pointy Maybe using comma operator will work.See the update.

Answer (score 2):

An option that *technically* fulfills the linter rules would be to declare `rest` upfront, destructure the `a` property into `rest`, and *then* use rest syntax to put the rest of the object into the `rest` variable name:

```js
const initObject = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
};
let rest;
({ a: rest, ...rest } = initObject);

console.log(rest);
```

Unfortunately, if you want to avoid `var`, you can't do it in just a single line like

```
let { a: rest, ...rest } = initObject
```

because when the left-hand side of the `{` declares a variable, each new variable name on the right side is *initialized* separately - that is, to the interpreter it looks a bit like

```
let rest = initObject.a;
let rest = <everything else in initObject>
```

But duplicate `let` identifiers for the same variable name is not permitted. You *could* do it in one line with `var`, for which duplicate identifiers are permitted:

```js
const initObject = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
};
var { a: rest, ...rest } = initObject;

console.log(rest);
```

But this is all a little bit odd. I'd prefer to configure/ignore the linter, or use something other than destructuring, as other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shallow copy of the object using `Object.assign()` and simply delete the property.

```js
const initObject = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
}

let rest = Object.assign({}, initObject);
delete rest.a;

console.log(rest);
console.log(initObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
const rest = ((o)=> (delete o.a,o))({...initObject});
```

```js
'use strict'

const initObject = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
}

const rest = ((o)=> (delete o.a,o))({...initObject});

console.log({initObject,rest});
```

Comment: Without the comma operator, I'm pretty sure eslint will still complain that `a` is unused.

Answer (score -1):

In order to omit (sanitize) the ID and the password properties, this is what finally worked for me in a single object.

This was the response from a Relationship between Products and Users Models.

```
   return {...product,
        author: [
            `username: ` + product['author'].username,
            `email: ` + product['author'].email,
        ]};
```

Otherwise for an array, I used:

```
    return products.map(product => [{ 
        'title' : product['title'],
        'description' : product['description'],
        'price' : product['price'],
        'updated' : product['updatedAt'],
        'author': {
            'username' : product['author'].username,
            'email' : product['author'].email,
        },                   
    }]);
```

I'm using PostgreSQL, Nest, Objection and Knex.