# How can I omit a property from JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Need to get rid of this warning without disabling the eslint. How do I remove a specific property from an JavaScript object? Something like:

```
const { foo, ...rest } = myObject;
```

I am seeing this warning:

```
'for' is assigned a value but never used.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

I want to get rid of this warning, is there any other solution for omitting the properties?

Comment: you can find a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151661/omit-property-variable-when-using-object-destructuring#answer-56151883

Comment: Is there any other way, or disabling the eslint is the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the eslint configuration. There are two ways to remove the warning.

1. Configure your eslint to not show warnings on unused variables.
   Set "no-unused-vars": "off" in . eslintrc. json
2. Rename the "foo" variable to "_foo". (This might or might not work depending on the eslint configuration)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of the warning, you can use

`/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */`

at the top of your file