# delete user.password in a typesafe way

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to delete the `password` key in a user object in a typesafe way but typescript keeps complaining.

```js
const user = db.findUnique({where: email:input.email});

// returning user without password
// OPTION 1 - eslint disable doesn't remove the yellow squiggly on the password variable
// @eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
const { password, ...userWithoutPassword } = user;
return userWithoutPassword;

// OPTION 2 - Unsafe return of an `any` typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
return omit(user, "password"); // using lodash
// this also leads to the same error
const userWithoutPassword: Omit<User, "password"> = omit(user, "password");
return userWithoutPassword;

// OPTION 3 - The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.
// I don't want to change the type definition of User to make password optional. It should be a new type
delete user.password;
return user;
```

What's the appropriate way to do this?

Comment: `return {...user, password: undefined};` works but doesn't really satisfy the criteria of the question which is to delete the key and return a type without the password key

Comment: You should probably stick to the first option. Check out the `ignoreRestSiblings` option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151661/omit-property-variable-when-using-object-destructuring

Comment: @TobiasS. Thanks. That works. The correct line to disable it I realized is `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars, @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`

Comment: Does something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvaRRm) answer your question? If so, I can write it up as an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jsejcksn Oh nice. Yeah that works. I changed it to delete password [here](https://tsplay.dev/wE4JkW). Can you clarify this line in the explanation `user as Partial<Pick<User, "password">>`. `user` still stays as type `User` when hovering but when I read the code it reads like `user` should be `{password?: string}` and that's it, since it's saying only the password field should be partial... so are the other keys still included, or maybe I'm misunderstanding the "as" functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type for `lodash`'s [`omit`](https://lodash.com/docs/#omit) ([source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/6e1ec4dbebfd3ba637918b2f7c1de22800d537e7/types/lodash/common/object.d.ts#L1937-L1964)) should produce a type that is structurally compatible with the desired type [`Omit<User, "password">`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys). It sounds like there might be a configuration issue in your project if you are seeing `any` as the return type of the `omit` function. (Have you installed `@types/lodash` in your project?) See example in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzhEx4F84DMorgIgBsIATAQwGcALAWgFML8BuAKBZgE8w64BVCulDgBeRCzhwAdmRB0AXHAowowSQHNWE4CQVKV6zXDogywQruWqN4uGEoUA7tB2LLBmwHoPRmAGMAdCzorCxYAK6SvjDAEJJwanQw-IIA6mhUEGEwAAr2TlAkcAAUAJQKAPKoMAA8yVAANAR2FI7O+AB8YhJecL6xSnBhAkKiJABG-liqJLySwACOYXRFCA5UgvJGJmZyqmBZ-samhOglhn2SA0OCCnUiXRJSMpv4AGIQEPj1Nlou+GRjXwARgATABmL4-LbHBT4LAfAACYzIUH8yIAXpDHrY8s5YUCAPrIkgE5qtApYuDBNgSKCJMJQOIoNBFa4NJq4ilnOA9CAAawAhEEWEA).

If, for some reason, you want to *mutate* the existing `user` object by deleting the `password` property (instead of creating a new object), you will have to use some  [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) in order to satisfy the compiler because it does not allow for modifying types in-place — see functional [predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (a.k.a. type guards) for more.

Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAdgQwFsIAuKOYRAS1wHMBubKKgEzIursZwkPyoA27SjQZMw+OHADuAe0RtyIrkwD0qqBGABjAHSYAvo0wAzAK65twKrNxRaW+EgDqVYAAtZZ4AAVJM+RYoAAoASjIAeUI3AB4nRAAaKAAiCSk5BWSAPgw1DW1bCigzBGQ0FgAjXRMaFhhcKgBHMwhg9Gl3JFJNPkESGjBvXV5+AQNQ7igC3CKSpDJ41FycHAJiMmSAMVlZZISmHFYN-ArtAEYAJgBmPYOe0Y2THYABCvxEXTeAL1uVqDSAgoNmcAPpvFgggEZFi-KBGTBMFgQARaaDBObISRQPyIaz4AQxHxUbQAazipSSqX80OyWVCuihgUmiC0ZkQdgxUCxUVi8UpjMyWUYBkwQA)

```ts
type User = {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  // etc.
};

function getUserWithoutPassword (): Omit<User, "password"> {
  // const user = db.findUnique({where: email:input.email});
  const user: User = {
    name: "Foo",
    id: "abc123",
    email: "foo@bar.baz",
    password: "1_bad_password",
  };

  delete (user as Partial<Pick<User, "password">>).password;
  return user as Omit<User, "password">;
}
```

---

```ts
delete (user as Partial<Pick<User, "password">>).password;
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In the statement above, `user` is being asserted as the type `{ password?: string }`, so the compiler will allow deletion of the optional value.

```ts
return user as Omit<User, "password">;
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And in the `return` statement, `user` is being asserted as a type that represents the result of the previous deletion operation.