# "password" is declared but its value is never read

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build the authentication part of logging in of my project. I'm using JS and this error keeps persisting no matter how many things I try changing or checking.
I keep checking why I can't get password's value to be read in the validating password part, but I can't make it work.

```
The error: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'password' before initialization
    at login (file:///C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/Proyectos%20VS/DoctorAppointmentBooking/backend/Controllers/authController.js:100:56)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

This is the 100th line in question:

```
const isPasswordMatched = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
```

Here's the code of the whole part:

```
import User from '../models/UserSchema.js'
import Doctor from '../models/DoctorSchema.js'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'


const generateToken = user=>{
    return jwt.sign(
        {id: user._id, 
        role: user.role}, 
        process.env.JWT_SECRET_key,
        {
            expiresIn: "15d",
        })



}
export const login = async(req, res) => {

    const { email, password } = req.body;
    

    try{
        
        let user = null;
        const patient = await User.findOne({ email });
        const doctor = await Doctor.findOne({ email });

        if(patient){
            user = patient
        }
        if (doctor){
            user = doctor
        }

        //check if user exists or not

        if(!user){
            return res.status(404).json({message: "User not found."})
        }

        //check password

        const isPasswordMatched = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        
        if(!isPasswordMatched){
            return res
            .status(400)
            .json({status: false, message: "Incorrect credentials"})
        }

        //get token

        const token = generateToken(user);

        const {password, role, appointments, ...rest} = user._doc
            res
                .status(200)
                .json({status: true, message: "Successfully login", 
                token, 
                data:{...rest},
                role});

    } catch (err){
        return res
            .status(500)
            .json({status: false, message: "Failed to login"})

    }
}
```

The user thing works, it checks if it exists in the database or not, but the password is the thing throwing the error. I can't ignore it because it won't let me connect with the database. This is the message I get when I try to log in:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message": "Failed to login"
}
```

Comment: For the lint error in the title which is not the error you are actually seeing `const {password, role, appointments, ...rest} = user._doc` is the line it is complaining about. You can either just clone the object and delete the things you do not need OR you can use tell eslint to ignore https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151661/omit-property-variable-when-using-object-destructuring

Comment: Won't this leak the encrypted password to the user logging in, even if they have the wrong password? (And wouldn't it also leak _everything_ returned by the `findOne` method? That could be emails, etc)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton actually I had no idea, I'm using a tutorial as a guide (I'm still a noob), but you are right, it will leak everything returned by the findOne method 

Answer (score 0):

In the outer scope you

```
const { email, password } = req.body;
```

Normally, this would make it available within the scope of the `try{` where you:

```
const isPasswordMatched = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
```

but you overwrite (hide) the `password` declared in the outer scope with the line

```
const {password, role, appointments, ...rest} = user._doc
```

which appears **after** you try to access it.

One way to fix? Don't destructure and instead use `req.body.password`.

Comment: thank you so much, you solved the problem. I didn't know I couldn't use password again, but req.body.password instead. Again, thank you so much!