# What is the best way to write functions that does not use its parameter in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Specifically, I am using react-semantic-ui's Select Form, which takes an onChange function. So I have defined my function as such:

```
const handleInputChange = function handleInputChange(event, data){// does something with data}
```

(don't mind the ugly syntax, that's airbnb style guide)

I am doing something with data, but I am not using the event parameter at all. What would be the best practice in this case, since it is generally a bad practice to declare a variable without using it?

Comment: @Andy — It's coming from inside the third-party component.

Comment: This question encourages opinions, but `_` seems to be very common name for unused parameters.

Comment: @evolutionxbox but my codebase is using _ for lodash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare a parameter for every argument before the one you want to use.

The idiomatic approach to marking a parameter as unused is to prefix its name with an underscore.

```
function handleInputChange(_event, data){
```

Some linters will recognise this and not emit a "unused variable" warning.

For example ESLint has a [`argsIgnorePattern` option](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern) (but it also has a [`args` option](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#args) that lets you specify `after-used`).

Comment: It's also very common to name a parameter simply underscore (`_`) if it's not used. However, it only works for *one* parameter, e.g., `function foo(_, _, myParam)` is not valid. It also might clashes with the Underscore/Lodash libraries (or others) which define an object called `_`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually by using **Js es6** you could code without unused argument:)

```js
function handleInputChange(...[, data]) {
  console.log(data);
}

handleInputChange('event', 123);
```

And bellow is a similar question you could check out:)
[Standard conventions for indicating a function argument is unused in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197927/standard-conventions-for-indicating-a-function-argument-is-unused-in-javascript)