# Best way to replace/remove text from a string inside an li tag

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a sitemap list in ExpressionEngine (so I don't have *too* much flexibility on how things are rendered) and I need to remove the word 'Parent' from a string if it exists.

Below is an example of HTML output:

```html
<li class="sitemap-item">
  <a href="">About Us Parent</a>

  <ul>
    <li class="sitemap-item">
      <a href="">About Us</a>

      <ul>
        <li class="sitemap-item">
          <a href="http://website.dev/about-us/meet-the-directors">Meet the Directors</a>

        </li>

        <li class="sitemap-item">
          <a href="">Partners</a>

        </li>

        <li class="sitemap-item">
          <a href="">Accreditation &amp; Awards</a>

        </li>

        <li class="sitemap-item">
          <a href="">Testimonials</a>

        </li>

        <li class="sitemap-item">
          <a href="http://website.dev/careers">Careers</a>

        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</li>
```

I tried the following jQuery with no luck, just doesn't replace the word at all:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('li:contains("Parent")')){
    $(this).replace('Parent','');
  };
});
```

As you can see I'm trying to do this with jQuery. Can anyone shed some light on the correct way to do this?

Comment: So you expect to get an `About Us` nested inside an other `About Us`???

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, lunch break! haha. Yes that's right as a parent category can have many sub categories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have a `replace` method, it's a native method for strings, meaning you have to get the text first *as a string*, for instance with `text()`, and then return the changed string back again

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li > a:contains("Parent")').text(function(_, txt) {
        return txt.replace('Parent','');
    });
});
```

Comment: But you are completly destroying HTML markup this way. Selector should be in this case: `'li > a:contains("Parent")'`

Comment: @A.Wolff - that's true, the entire markup in the LI would be replaced by the text, edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace()` method with a regex to make sure you replace all instances of the word. `replace()` with strings only replaces the first occurance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var elements = $('li');
  elements.html(elements.html().replace(/Parent/gi, ''));
});
```

Comment: The downside is that you could unbind any previous events/datas bound to these LI elements

Comment: That's true. Ideally he would use a selector closer to `$('li.sitemap-item > a')`.